# Manipulate the system time for a given command

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run command with specific date in history.
Let say today is 12.Nov.2019 and I need to run one command with date of 10th. Is there any possibility of setting date on fly ?

```
date -d '1 day ago' /path/to/command
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Which command do you have in mind?

Comment: You want to bypass subscription limitation, don't you? :-P. I don't think there is a way to do this. Anyway. This question should be more suited for [su].

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/faketime.1.html

Answer (score 3):

Use can you `faketime` to run a command with given time:

> ***faketime*** - manipulate the system time for a given command

Because you didn't tell us what command and time you want to run,
I suppose that you want to run `/path/to/command` on `Oct 10th, 2019`.

- Run `/path/to/command` in *2 days ago*:

```
faketime -f -2d /path/to/command
```

- Run `/path/to/command` on *Oct 10th, 2019*:

```
faketime -f '2019-11-10' /path/to/command
```

Comment: Good answer. How does this work? LD_PRELOAD will be modified and system calls will be intercept to fake time.